# How do I stop an 'allow incoming network connections' dialogue box popping up every time I use PhantomJS?

Tags: python, macos, phantomjs, firewall

I know this may be more of an OS related question, but I'm asking here because I wanted to see if anyone has found a solution for phantomJS.

[The dialogue box that appears every time my script is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMDer.png)

I read the answers on the apple stack exchange site where the question was asked (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-to-get-rid-of-firewall-accept-incoming-connections-dialog). I was afraid to try the first two because they were confusing and I didn't want to mess with that stuff without having at least some idea what I was doing. The third solution I tried without any success.

I've also (obviously) tried every permutation of settings in my firewall settings without any success.

I'm adding my code below, I am very aware of how flawed and amateurish it is. I am a novice at python, coding and computers in general, but having this dialogue box pop up every time I want to change or improve my code is very irritating. (If you have constructive criticism to offer by all means share, but my question is specifically related to the phantomJS dialogue box that seems to afflict novice and expert alike.)

```
import selenium.webdriver

_range= range(1, 4)
def simple_scraper():     
    driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS()
    print('driver opened')   
    for num in _range:
        driver.get('http://xkcd.com/%d' % (num))
        print('finding page')
        global cartoon_name 
        cartoon_name =driver.title
        print('http://xkcd.com/%d' % (num), cartoon_name)               
        print('Downloading page http://xkcd.com/%d...' % (num))
        print('cartoon name 1: %s' % (cartoon_name))
simple_scraper()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out how to do this?

Comment: @nick, Unfortunately not. I ended up just switching to `requests` as that was actually much better suited to my needs.